# Threading and Dropbox

Tags: multithreading, dropbox

I'm developing an application that might use Dropbox as it's storage.

My question is, you can link folders between computers, so that more than 1 person could upload/download to/from the same folder.

Do I have to worry about threading? What happens if while a person is downloading a file, the other person is updating the same file. Does dropbox lock the file while one operation is being done on it? If not, I guess I have to handle it in my application correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do have to worry about this.

Dropbox uses optimistic concurrency. Every file has a `rev` (revision) that you can reference when uploading a file (e.g. via [`/files_put`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put)). So the basic idea is that when you download a file, you keep track of the `rev`, and when you upload the file, you pass that `rev` as the `parent_rev` parameter. If the file has been changed in the meantime by a different user (via a shared folder) or the same user (via a different device), the `rev` won't match. What happens then is dictated by the `autorename` parameter. If you specify `true`, the file will get renamed on conflict. If you specify `false`, the upload will fail altogether, and your app can decide what to do.

Essentially, you can't stop users from updating files simultaneously on multiple devices, but you *can* (and should) deal with these conflicts in your app, and the `rev` is what lets you ensure no data is lost.

Comment: Thanks. Time for some research!

Comment: Does dropbox provide an example to read from the rev file, and process it?

Comment: I don't think so... but the `rev` is returned from `/metadata`, `/delta`, `/files (GET)`, etc. (anywhere you see a file's metadata).

Answer (score 0):

When a conflict happens dropbox will make a copy of the file and the file name contains the date and host name (for example, for MarkoLaptop as hostname and 21st of January 2015 for conflict date will generate a file called `README.TXT (MarkoLaptop's conflicted copy 2015-01-21)`), so if you can handle it in the app, that's great <3

Comment: So, essentially, I would have to handle it in my application. BUT, what's to stop someone from using drop box directly then? I guess nothing.

Comment: Yes :) It's actually a feature :) Or a bug if you look at it that way :) Amazon S3 maybe as alternative? :) Or http://sparkleshare.org/ + a free git hosting service like bitbucket if you don't expect much data